# Form Submission to a Directory?

Tags: php, html, forms

Is it considered bad practice to set an `action` attribute as a directory and relying on the server to refer to the index file of the directory? So instead of the action attribute being set to `search/index.php`, should the attribute be set to `search` instead? I am using PHP to handle form submission. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Seems like it never worked. Now I am setting the action attribute to `search/index.php` and using `mod_rewrite` to remove index.php

Comment: In reference to your edit, if you really don't want the user seeing `index.php`, you can send the form to something like `processform.php`, process the form data, and then use [`header("Location")`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to redirect the user to `/search`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it considered bad practice to set an action attribute as a directory and relying on the server to refer to the index file of the directory?

Not even slightly. Having explicit `index`s is generally considered ugly and overly verbose while having explicit `.php`s will tie you to a specific backend technology (although it is possible to change to not-PHP and still have `.php` in URLs).

The server routing rules should be considered part of your application.

Answer (score 2):

It would be considered bad practice to send the information to somewhere that can be changed, yes.

Right now, the directory might be using `index.php` as the index file. But what happens when someone changes `/search/` to use `abcd.php` as the index file instead? Now your form is intending for it to go to `index.php`, but it's actually going to `abcd.php` instead.